# Longest path in $n\times n$ grid

Tags: graph-theory

Consider an $n\times n$ grid graph. It is easy to construct (self-avoiding) paths in it of length $n(n+2)$, by starting at the upper left corner, going downwards to the lower left corner, going right by 1 edge, going upwards, going right by 1 edge etc (zig zagging). How does one rigorously show that this is indeed the maximum possible length of a path in the grid? Furthermore, is there a formula counting the number of said paths?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There cannot be any longer paths, since each intersection can only be used once, and there are $(n+1)^2 = n(n+2) + 1$ intersections. Any path of $i$ nodes is of length $i-1$. The only exception is if (hamiltonian) loops counts as self-avoiding, and exists.